# Creating new layer in order to fix duplicate categories in GRASS?

Tags: layers, network, grass-7.0

I'm trying to run a network analysis in Grass 7.0 following this tutorial: http://www.ing.unitn.it/~grass/docs/tutorial_641_en/htdocs/esercitazione/network_analysis/node3.html

Since I'm new to Grass I already got stuck when trying to create a new layer in order to eliminate duplicate categories from my lines layer.
The query I use is:

> v.category --overwrite --verbose input=network_connect output=network_cat3 type=line layer=3 cat=1

The output is:

> ERROR: Required parameter  not set:
>           (Action to be executed.)
>   (Fri Aug 19 16:46:37 2016) Command executed (0 Sek)

I translated this from German, so if anything in the Error message seems fishy, that's my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the tutorial was missing the command "option=add" so that

> v.category --overwrite --verbose input=network_connect output=network_cat3 type=line layer=3 cat=1 option=add

is the final command.